# Steam API grabbing a list of prices

Tags: python

I was trying to grab a list of prices. So far my code for such a thing is:

```
def steamlibrarypull(steamID, key):
    #Pulls out a CSV of Steam appids.
    steaminfo = {
        'key': key,
        'steamid': steamID,
        'format':'JSON',
        'include_appinfo':'1'
    }
    r = requests.get('http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/', params=steaminfo)
    d = json.loads(r.content)
    I = d['response']['games']
    B = {}
    for games in I:
        B[games['name'].encode('utf8')] = games['appid']
    with open('games.csv', 'w') as f:
        for key, value in B.items():
            f.write("%s,%s\r\n" % (key, value))
    return B
```

But I'd like to be able to do a request.get that'll take this dictionary and ouput out a list of prices. https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI Seems to require the need of a CSV list but is that really necessary?

Comment: i've posted enough information to get you started but you will need to learn a little more python to make this work.  you will need to learn how to add a new key:value pair to a dictionary, how to check if a key exists, ect.  there is a decent amount of code required to return these prices and to make the code efficient you will need a better understanding of python.  look at the code i posted previously.  the methods i use within are what you will need to pull these prices.  try putting the api request into the browser to see the json.  this is a more in depth then can be posted here.

Answer (score 2):

this is a non formal steam api meaning steam modifies as they see fit.  currently it **does not support multiple appids** as noted [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/2kz2ay/steam_store_api_multiple_app_id_lists_no_longer/).
to use it to get the price of a game you would go

```
http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=237110&cc=us&filters=price_overview
```

working from the code you have above you will need to know how to iterate through the dictionary and update the store price once you get it back.

```
def steamlibrarypull(steamID, key):
#Pulls out a CSV of Steam appids.
    steaminfo = {
        'key': key,
        'steamid': steamID,
        'format':'JSON',
        'include_appinfo':'1'
    }
    r = requests.get('http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/', params=steaminfo)
    d = json.loads(r.content)
    response = d['response']['games']
    games = {}
    for game in response:
        getprice = requests.get('http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=%d&filters=price_overview&cc=us' % game['appid'])
        if getprice.status_code == 200:
            rjson = json.loads(getprice.text)
            # use the appid to fetch the value and convert to decimal
            # appid is numeric, cast to string to lookup the price
            try:
                price = rjson[str(game['appid'])]['data']['price_overview']['initial'] * .01
            except:
                price = 0
            games[game['name']] = {'price': price, 'appid': game['appid']}
```

this will return the following dictionary:

```
{u'Half-Life 2: Episode Two': {'price': 7.99, 'appid': 420}
```

it would be easier to navigate via appid instead of name but as per your request and original structure this is how it should be done.  this then gives you the name, appid and price that you can work with further or write to a file.
note that this does not include a sleep timer, if your list of games is long you should sleep your api calls for 2 seconds before making another one or the api will block you and will not return data which will cause an error in python when you parse the price.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "steam.py", line 64, in <module>
    print steamlibrarypull(76561197960434622, key)
  File "steam.py", line 49, in steamlibrarypull
    ids = ', '.join(ids)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
 I received that as an error.

Comment: i've added a completed and testing working code for this so you can see how it is done.  please re-read and see my edits.  multi-appids are no longer supported so you will need to fetch each one by one.  best practice is to sleep on each request so that you are not blocked.  you will need to work through any other issues as i tested this on a block of 237 games without issue.  i listed 1 result above so you could see the expected output.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "steam.py", line 51, in <module>
    print steamlibrarypull(76561197960434622, key)
  File "steam.py", line 49, in steamlibrarypull
    price = rjson[str(game['appid'])]['data']['price_overview']['initial'] * .01
KeyError: 'data'
That seems to appear D:

Comment: yes, some items may not have a price associated with them for one reason or another.  you should either wrap it in a try/except or test it with an if statement.  or simply, don't convert it to a decimal.  if you don't convert it you will get back a non decimal string.

Comment: So would it be: try:
price = rjson[str(game['appid'])]['data']['price_overview']['initial'] * .01
except KeyError: 
  pass

Comment: Yes. Or just drop the * .01

Comment: Now this error pops up, TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str